# Deploying apps via CodePush or AppHub

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am building a system that allows users to build up their own apps with React Native. This takes place on a React website. Each user will have a base application that holds the skeleton code, however the app they build on the website should be able to deployed to the phone easily and live in the skeleton app.

Is it possible to firstly do this? Also, would AppHub or Microsoft's CodePush allow me to do this?

I realise that these apps are built for deploying new releases, however I am wanting to push specific code, to specific users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds technically possible. And you would have to carefully read the respective TOS to see if it violates them.

Answer (score 10):

Here's some research. We ended up moving forward with CodePush

```
|                                      | apphub.io              | codepush.tools             | react-native-auto-updater | getsiphon.com        | rollout.io                              | 
|--------------------------------------|------------------------|----------------------------|---------------------------|----------------------|-----------------------------------------|-
| Open Source Client                   | y                      | y                          | y                         | n                    |                                         | 
| Image Support                        | y                      | y                          | n                         | y                    |                                         | 
| HTTPS                                | y                      | y                          | n/a                       | y                    |                                         | 
| CLI Tooling                          | y                      | y                          | n/a                       | y                    |                                         | 
| Gradual Rollout                      | n                      | y                          | n/a                       | n                    |                                         | 
| SLA                                  | "via ""Contact Us"""   | ? (beta)                   | n/a                       | "via ""Contact Us""" |                                         | 
| Cost                                 | "via ""Contact Us""    |                            |                           |                      |                                         | 
|                                      |                        |                            |                           |                      |                                         | 
| ""Scale Plan"" (no private hosting): |                        |                            |                           |                      |                                         | 
| 1100$/mo for 5m DAU                  |                        |                            |                           |                      |                                         | 
| 2100$/mo for 10m DAU"                | ? (free in beta)       | n/a                        | "via ""Contact Us"""      |                      | Ask apphub about multi-env / multi-file | 
| On-Premise                           | y                      | n                          | n/a                       | y                    |                                         | 
| Cloud Hosting                        | y                      | y                          | n/a                       | y                    |                                         | 
| Documented API                       | y                      | n                          | y                         | n                    |                                         | 
| Web UI                               | y                      | n                          | n/a                       | n                    |                                         | 
| iOS                                  | y                      | y                          | y                         | y                    |                                         | 
| Android                              | y                      | y                          | y                         | y                    |                                         | 
| Multiple Environments                | """Debug"" and normal" | y                          | n                         | n                    |                                         | 
| Known Packaging                      | y                      | y                          | y                         | n                    |                                         | 
| Contact                              | support@apphub.io      | codepushfeed@microsoft.com |                           |                      |                                         | 
| Delta Updates                        | n                      | y                          | ?                         | ?                    |                                         |
```